# Convert Y-m-d date format to d-m-Y

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, datetime-format

I bought a wordpress theme and one of its templates to return a date in format Y-m-d. This is the code:

```
<li><strong><?php _e("Start Date:" , SH_NAME); ?></strong><span><?php echo  sh_set( $settings, 'start_date' ); ?></span></li>
```

where 'start_date' returns Y-m-d. Please, someone tell how to make 'start_date' do return m-d-Y format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  In php there is function date() and strtotime().
I made this to work good,  but didn't test

```
        <li>
    <strong>
    <?php _e("Start Date:" , SH_NAME); ?>
</strong>
    <span>
    <?php echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime(sh_set( $settings, 'start_date' )));?></span>
    </li>
```

Comment: Fine. It works. I really appreciate your kindly help.